# Progressive non-linear algorithm for increasing discount

Tags: algorithm, math

A system has to support 100 users and the price for support is 3

A system has to support 10 000 users and the price for support is 1

I have to devise an algorithm to give me the price in between so it will gradually rise with the number of users.

I tried to multiply the number of users by 0.0002 to get the discount value and I got

300 users * 0.0002 = 0.06 discount, so price for support = 2.94
total income = 300 * 2.94 = 882

5000 users * 0.0002 = 1 discount, so price for support = 2
total income = 5000 * 2 = 10 000

8000 users * 0.0002 = 1.6 discount, so price for support = 1.4
total income = 8000 * 1.4 = 11 200

10 000 users * 0.0002 = 2 discount, so price for support = 1
total income = 8000 * 1.4 = 10 000

So you see after a given point I am actually having more users but receiving less payment.

I am not a mathematician and I now this is not really a programming question, but I don't know where else to ask this. I will appreciate  if someone can help me with any information. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone move this to MathOverflow?

Comment: @El does it look like a research-level problem? [math.se] perhaps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`price = n * (5 - log10(n))` will work for `100 < n < 10000`.

Just make sure you're using base-10 log and not natural (base-e) log. If your language doesn't have base-10 log normally, you can calculate it like this:
`function log10(x) { return log(x)/log(10); }`.

For 100 users, that's `100 * (5 - log10(100))`, which gives `100 * (5 - 2)`, which is 300.

For 1000 users, that's `1000 * (5 - log10(1000))`, which gives `1000 * (5 - 3)`, which is 2000.

For 10000 users, that's `10000 * (5 - log10(10000))`, which gives `10000 * (5 - 4)`, which is 10000.

Let's pick some more random figures.
2500 users: `2500 * (5 - log10(2500))` gives us `2500 * (5 - 3.39794)`, which is 4005.
6500 users: `6500 * (5 - log10(6500))` gives us `6500 * (5 - 3.81291)`, which is 7716.
8000 users: `8000 * (5 - log10(8000))` gives us `8000 * (5 - 3.90309)`, which is 8775.

Should work out about right for what you're modelling.

Comment: Here's a plot of the price per user. Notice that 100 = 3, 1000 = 2, 10000 = 1. Here's the link: http://www3.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%285+-+Log%5Bx%5D%2FLog%5B10%5D%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+100%2C10000%7D%5D

Comment: Just keep in mind that as `n -> 100000`, `price -> 0`. You'll probably want to cap price at a minimum of 1 in your code.

Comment: Thanks Polynomial! I enjoy seeing people that know their stuff. This will work just perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Scaling the price per user linearly didn't work as you showed, but you can try scaling the total income linearly instead.

- total income for   100 users = 300
- total income for 10000 users = 10000
- total income for   *n* users = (*n*-100) / (10000-100) * (10000-300) + 300

You know that the total income for n users is the price for support per user times the number of users, that means, now you have to find the function *f*(*n*) such that *f*(*n*) * *n* = (*n*-100) / (10000-100) * (10000-300) + 300.

And if you have to show that as the total income always increase, the price for support always decrease, just show that *f'*(*n*) ≤ 0 when 100 ≤ n ≤ 10000.